# ValueError: 'AccessPolicy' instance needs to have a primary key value before this relationship can be used (after upgrade Django from 2.2 to 4.2)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm upgrading the legacy project from Django 2.2 to Django 4.2. Everything works fine except the model, where ManyToMany field is used.

The model:

```py
# models.py
class AccessPolicy(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    version_hash = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    read_only = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text=('Some text'))
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Access Policy'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Access Policies'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self._meta.object_name} Object ({self.pk})'
```

The form:

```py
# forms.py
class AccessPolicyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    external_id = forms.CharField(disabled=True, required=False)
    rules = forms.CharField(widget=QueryBuilderWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = AccessPolicy
        fields = 'name', 'external_id', 'read_only', 'rules', 'users',

    def clean_external_id(self):
        external_id = self.cleaned_data.get('external_id')
        if not external_id:
            return md5(f"{str(self.instance.created)} {self.cleaned_data.get('name')} {self.data.get('rules')}")
        return external_id

    def clean_rules(self) -> CleanedRules:
        raw_rules: RawRules = json.loads(self.cleaned_data.get('rules'))
        conditional_serializer = RulesSerializer(data=raw_rules)
        if not conditional_serializer.is_valid():
            raise ValidationError(conditional_serializer.errors)
        return conditional_serializer.validated_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.version_hash = hash_dict(self.cleaned_data.get('rules'))
        return super().save(commit)

    def _save_m2m(self):
        self.instance.rules.all().delete()
        self._save_condition()
        self._save_users()

    def _save_users(self):
        self.instance.users.clear()
        self.instance.users.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('users'))

    def _save_condition(self):
        root_condition = RulesSerializer().create(self.cleaned_data.get('rules'))
        root_condition.access_policy = self.instance
        root_condition.save()
```

The admin file:

```py
# admin.py
class AccessPolicyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AccessPolicyForm
    list_display = 'name',
    search_fields = 'name',
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {
            'widget': FilteredSelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 20},
                                             verbose_name='linked users',
                                             is_stacked=False)
        },
    }

    def get_form(self, request, obj: AccessPolicy = None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
        data = self._get_form_data(obj or AccessPolicy())
        form.declared_fields[AUTHORIZATION_CONDITION_CHILDREN].initial = json.dumps(data)
        return form

    def _get_form_data(self, access_policy: AccessPolicy):
        return pipe(access_policy,
                    AccessRulesGenerator.get_root_rule,
                    RulesSerializer,
                    extract_data)
```

This code works fine and without errors under Django 2.2, but under Django 4.2 gives an error:

```bash
'AccessPolicy' instance needs to have a primary key value before this relationship can be used.
```

I understand that I need to save the instance of the model before adding any `m2m` fields and I have to add the `m2m` field with the `.add()` method. I tried few modifcations in `save()` and `_save_m2m()` methods, but without success. Where should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create temporary instance of `AccessPolicy`, then the problem with missing `pk` no longer exists.

```py
# admin.py

company_name = 'Temporary policy to delete, because we only need its pk for saving users.'
temporary_policy = AccessPolicy.objects.create(name=company_name)
data = self._get_form_data(obj or temporary_policy)
all_temp_policies = AccessPolicy.objects.filter(name=company_name)

# More than one policy with given name is generated, so I'm deleting them in a loop
for tp in all_temp_policies:
    tp.delete()
```

The solution isn't the best in my opinion, because I'm generating few policies with the same name and then I've to delete them. But the problem with primary key disappeared.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a similar problem & I don't have a solution yet for 1 of my 2 cases. Personally, I think the error text is misleading. The problem isn't that the object needs a key, it's that no related models (can) link to it. Up to 3.2, when you queried a related model's relationship from the current model (through the related model's `related_name`), it happily returned `None`, which made sense to me, because there are no linked records yet. Now you have to jump through hoops and make your code ugly to catch and ignore this inane exception.

Comment: OK, in my case (a cache maintenance routine), I solved it by conditionally attempting to delete related caches with `if self.pk is not None or type(child_instance).__name__ not in ["RelatedManager", "ManyRelatedManager"]:`